# "Name that game" type of question is on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

See [What's the name of this board game?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/834/)

In [Gaming.SE](http://Gaming.StackExchange.com) this type of question is very popular. Should we consider them on-topic?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that's a great kind of question for this site. We have [an example already](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/607/a-game-with-multiplying-aliens-and-random-weapons), where it's worked out very well. (Speaking of which, we should probably decide on one tag for both of these).

These questions have an objective answer (the original game the questioner was thinking about). They can have multiple potential answers, if the questioner wasn't specific enough, or some answers may provide more detail that would allow the questioner to positively identify the game in question. If there is not enough detail to answer at first, this can be clarified through comments and edits to the original question.

So yes, I think that this format works very well for StackExchange, and think that it's definitely on topic for this one.

Comment: In the months since this was first brought up, Jeff has [questioned their value](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1455/8366), and the biggest concerns that arose are that they don't require subject matter expertise to answer, and that no one other than the OP can truly know if they've been answered, meaning that they can easily become broken windows. (Upvotes tend to mean "I believe this is a good guess" rather than "This answer is useful".) As long as those issues don't become problems here, those questions will probably fit in well.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to always use the [**identify-this-game**] tag instead of the [**Name-that-game**] tag. It should be set as a tag synonym.

This tag name come from [gaming.stackexchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) (71 questions with this tag so far), so I think we should keep it as a standard.

Comment: So wit will be.